# Printing a list or vector of strings

Tags: clojure

If I have a list of strings:

`("String 1" "String 2" "String 3")`

or a vector of strings:

`["String 1" "String 2" "String 3"]`

threading either through (map println) produces this (for lists):

`(String 1
String 2
nil String 3
nil nil)`

and this for vectors:

`(String 1
String 2
String 3
nil nil nil)`

What's going on here? Where are the nils coming from? How do I get this?:

`String 1
String 2
String 3`

(No nils, no parentheses, just newlines.)

Answer (score 4):

A `nil` is *returned* every time you call `println`. The *value* of

```
(map println ["String 1" "String 2" "String 3"])
```

is

```
(nil nil nil)
```

Printing the strings is a side-effect.

Try

```
(dorun (map println ["String 1" "String 2" "String 3"]))
```

which gives

```
String 1
String 2
String 3
nil
```

As you see, you still get one `nil` - returned by the `dorun`.

Comment: Neat, thanks for the explanation and solution! When I looked dorun up on Grimoire, most of the examples involved this kind of thing. Do you know any other examples where you emphasize the side effects? (Is that the right way to talk about what dorun does?)

Comment: `do`, `doseq`, `while`, `when`, `..`, `doto` and `dorun` are all side-effect oriented. Printing is the most common case for demonstration purposes because it is clear and requires little setup or context. You also see these things used when setting values on a mutable Object, modifying some reference type or altering the contents of an external database, or any other action of global effect where the return value is unimportant beyond its scope.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something to print

```
String 1
String 2
String 3
```

in the REPL, when provided the input `["String 1" "String 2" "String 3"]`, not printing any parens or `nil` result:

```
user> (symbol (clojure.string/join \newline ["String 1" "String 2" "String 3"]))
String 1
String 2
String 3
```

This is a Stupid Clojure Trick, of marginal utility. It can output exactly what you wanted, but why do you want to use the REPL at all if you don't want the return value? Why not write a proper `-main` function that parses user input and outputs exactly what you like?

Comment: I've got the main functionality of my program running. I want to implement a few more features, and then the final step for a 1.0 will be to write the proper -main function :)